# What is the best kafka ui dashboard to use with kafkajs?

Tags: user-interface, apache-kafka, dashboard

Which dashboard ui is best to use with kafka when you are using kafkajs? I found there is one called kafkaq-monitor, (https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafkaq-monitor), but it has 0 weekly downloads and does not look to be actively maintained.

Are there any better kafka dashboards available that are free to use and quick and easy to setup from npm? I need one that will work in both a local dev environment, on staging, and on production as well.

Comment: The client library doesn't matter. Any Kafka UI should work with any client language. Asking for offsite resources, is considered off topic for Stackoverflow, however - [help]

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I didn't realize that at first. I ended up using one known as Kafdrop.